# A message body reader for Java class com.archive.Response, and Java type class com.archive.Response, and MIME media type text/x-json was not found

Tags: java, json, http, jackson

I try to use `jackson` to convert an http json response to a java object.

```
        webResource.accept("application/json");
        ClientResponse clientResponse = webResource.path("routingRequest")
                .queryParam("options", rr.options)
                .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE)
                .get(ClientResponse.class);

        Response routingResponse = clientResponse.getEntity(Response.class);
```

However I get this error:

```
A message body reader for Java class com.archive.Response, and Java type class com.archive.Response, and MIME media type text/x-json was not found
```

and

```
Feb 17, 2015 12:18:34 PM com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientResponse getEntity
SEVERE: A message body reader for Java class com.waze.routing.automation.dto.archive.Response, and Java type class com.waze.routing.automation.dto.archive.Response, and MIME media type text/x-json was not found
Feb 17, 2015 12:18:34 PM com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientResponse getEntity
SEVERE: The registered message body readers compatible with the MIME media type are:
*/* ->
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.FormProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.StringProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.ByteArrayProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.FileProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.InputStreamProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.DataSourceProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLJAXBElementProvider$General
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.ReaderProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.DocumentProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.SourceProvider$StreamSourceReader
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.SourceProvider$SAXSourceReader
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.SourceProvider$DOMSourceReader
  com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONJAXBElementProvider$General
  com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONArrayProvider$General
  com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONObjectProvider$General
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLRootElementProvider$General
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLListElementProvider$General
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLRootObjectProvider$General
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.EntityHolderReader
  com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONRootElementProvider$General
  com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONListElementProvider$General
  com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JacksonProviderProxy
```

how can i target the miss-match problem easily?

**UPDATE**

I even tried to ignore as much members as possible:

```
public class RoutingResponse {
    @JsonIgnore public Response response;
    @JsonIgnore public Coordinate[] coords;
    public Coordinate segCoords;
}
```

and still fails to parse the JSON response:

```
{
    "response": {
        "routeName": "המכבים, באר שבע",
        "results": [{
        }],
        "streetNames": ["ג'ו יוסף אלון", null, "הפלמ\"ח", "המכבים", "נגבה", "דבורה", "אהוד בן גרא"],
        "tileIds": [],

        "displayRoute": true
    },
    "coords": [{
        "x": 34.78103644431032,
        "y": 31.243934961900017,
        "z": NaN
    }, {
        "x": 34.779020165815155,
        "y": 31.242382384889336,
        "z": NaN
    }],
    "segCoords": null
}
```

Comment: Check if you have included all the dependencies/jars for jersey/jackson

Comment: what are "all"of them?

Comment: Does the web service you're calling return a com.archive.Response?

Comment: it should. but my q is how do i know where the parse fails?

Answer (score 0):

The reason is the media type of the response:text/x-json
It must be "application/json" to be accepted by your library.

Comment: but i have ` webResource.accept("application/json");`

Comment: yes, that is what your client expects, but the server provides "text/x-json", what is said in the error message

Comment: so how can i convert it? or fix this? and how does it work anyway if the client expected something different than the server  provides?